# Why this C program outputs a negative number?

Tags: c, unsigned

I have assigned the complement value in an unsigned variable.

Then why this C program outputs a negative number?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int Value = 4;         /*   4 = 0000 0000  0000 0100 */  
    unsigned int result = 0;

    result = ~ Value;               /* -5 = 1111 1111  1111 1011 */  

    printf("result = %d", result);  /* -5             */

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question should be: "Why does the compiler not emit a warning when I compile this code?". The answer is: "Turn up the warnings on the compiler. (eg -Wall)"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `%d` format specifier instructs `printf` to treat the argument as a signed integer. Use `%u` instead.

Answer (score 4):

It's because %d is the signed int format placeholder, so it's getting converted. Use %u for unsigned.